# Why does a function value of an object not have its own scope?

Tags: javascript, scope, closures, this

The following code outputs `dafunc:  this.foo = bar`

```
var myObject = {
    foo: "bar",
    dafunc: function() {
        console.log("dafunc:  this.foo = " + this.foo);
    }
};
myObject.dafunc();
```

Why?

Why doesn't the function `dafunc` have its own scope where `this.foo` is undefined? Don't functions have their own `this` in Javascript?

Comment: See: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch1.md#its-scope

Comment: In virtually all OOP languages, `this` (or equivalent) refers to the object the function is a member of. It sounds like you expect `this` to behave like a *variable scope*; for that there's already the, well, *variable scope*, `this` doesn't have to duplicate that functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions don't have their own `this`, it is decided by the caller.

If you do `myObject.daFunc()` that will be `myObject`.

If you do `var x = myObject.daFunc;  x();` it will not be something useful.

If you do `myObject.daFunc.apply(somethingElse)` it will be `somethingElse`.

---

I think where the confusion comes from is that the `this` inside of the function is unrelated to the `this` in the scope that defined the function. So in that way, the function does have its own `this`.

```
var myObject = {
  foo: "bar",
  dafunc: function() {
      setTimeout(function(){
        // now we lost "this", this doesn't work
        console.log("dafunc:  this.foo = " + this.foo);
      }, 0);
  } 
};
```

This is where the "fat-array" syntax that some versions of Javascript have comes in. Here `this` carries over from the defining scope:

```
      setTimeout( () => {
        // fat array "preserves" this
        console.log("dafunc:  this.foo = " + this.foo);
      }, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call it like this: `myObject.dafunc();` the `this` value is `myObject`

in your code, if you try foo what happens? (its `undefined`)

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, `this` refers to the object the function is being called from. The scope is considered using the object. Since function is called using the `myobject` object, it consists of myobject's scope which has foo defined. I think if said just foo instead of this.foo, it would consider the new foo variable, not the one from myobject's scope.